# how do i merge parameters in axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

i want `url1` and `url2` merge paramaters where `url` has a `query` and I want it to use it on `url2` which has not

```
    params: { 
      query: `${query}` },
      headers: { Accept: "application/json" }
  })

  const getMarket=axios.get(url[1],
    {
      params: { 
        vs_currency:'usd',
        per_page:100,
     },
      headers: { Accept: "application/json" }
    })

    
  const requestedData = async() =>{
      axios.all([getSearch,getMarket])
      .then(axios.spread((res1 ,res2)=> setRetrievedData(...res1.data,res2))).catch(error=>error)
    }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    requestedData()
  },[query])
```

`ur1` and `url2` have different endpoints I wanted to use the parameter from  another endpoint which I think it's impossible for me.

Comment: Does spelling `accept` correctly in `headers` fix things for you?

Comment: unfortunately no, that was a typo i re-wrote it earlier

Comment: `.then()` accepts a function but `console.log() `returns undefined. Also, `params` and `headers` should be in the same object. In summary, all you really need is `axios.get(url, { params: { query: "bitcoin" } }).then(res => setRetrievedData(res.data))`

Comment: FYI that API doesn't respond with any `config` property. It has `coins`, `exchanges`, `icos`, `categories` and `nfts`

Answer (score 1):

This should get you working. You're not actually returning or using the data from the fetch anywhere, just logging it.

```
const getData = async () => {
  const bitcoinData = await axios.get(url,
    {
      params: { query: "bitcoin" }
    }
  )

  console.log(bitcoinData)
  setRetrievedData(bitcoinData)
}

useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, [])
```

Comment: @Phil whoops, right you are. Haven't used Axios in a while.